# Malloc Allocates Out of Bound Memory Address

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf

I am have the below snippet of code which allocates the memory out of the bounds:

```
char *str1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE);
printf ("str1 = ");
scanf("%s", &str1);
int n = strlen(str1);
```

Initially I was getting a `Segmentation Fault` in `strlen()`. After playing with gdb I came to know that `str1` was at a address which was out of bounds. Below shown is the gdb output.

```
(gdb) print str1
$1 = 0x636261 <Address 0x636261 out of bounds>
```

**Note:** The breakpoint was set on the line where `strlen()` is called. Also, `BUF_SIZE` is set as `#define BUF_SIZE 10`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Add `memset(str,0,BUFSIZE)` before 'reading' into it

Comment: Don't use `scanf` use `fscanf` or `fgets` instead.

Comment: @Algo: Why? I usually advise against `*scanf()` myself, but in this case that's hardly the issue, especially if suggesting `fscanf()` instead, which has just the same issues as `scanf()`...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be passing `str1`, not `&str1`, to `scanf()`.

`scanf()` expects a `char *` for the `"%s"` format; you pass the address of a `char *`.  This does not lead to happiness.

Since BUF_SIZE is so small — just 10, you say — you need to use:

```
if (scanf("%9s", str1) != 1)
    …process error or EOF…
```

This will protect you against buffer overflow.  You should specify the size every time you use `%s` (unless you use the POSIX modifier `%ms` to [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html), but then the rules all change).  If you don't, `scanf()` can write outside the bounds of your string variable without knowing.

You should also check that `malloc()` succeeds.  Always.  Every time.

---

Note that compiling with GCC and `-Wall` (or `-Wformat`) will point out the error of your ways. If you're using GCC, you should always compile with `-Wall` (and preferably `-Wextra` too — I use more options than that) to get better error reporting.

For a file with your code in it, GCC said:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
```

or 'error' when compiling with `-Werror` too, which I regard as good practice.

I note in passing that GDB is telling me that you probably entered `abc` as the string on a little-endian (e.g. Intel) machine.  The value `0x636261` corresponds to that.  You overwrote the pointer returned by `malloc()` because you passed the address of `str1` instead of the value in `str1` — leaving memory corruption.

Answer (score 4):

You have several problems in your code:

1. Don't read a string *over* the pointer, you meant `scanf("%s", str1);`, drop the `&`!
2. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
3. Don't assume that allocations succeed.
4. Don't use `scanf()` for this, it's very dangerous since you're not passing it any information about the available buffer size. It's better to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: By 3rd point do you mean that should I verify that pointer returned from malloc isn't NULL? And regarding 1st point it was my bad. Debuggers can't help in that :)

Comment: It was great to know the 2nd point also that it automatically promotes the void *.

Comment: @sidkamaria Yes, you should check that the returned pointer isn't `NULL` before assuming that it isn't.